# Pass parameter in method

Tags: javascript, function, asp.net-core

I have this code

```
var txt;

function change(){
    txt = "@Utils.GeneratePass()";      
    document.getElementById("password_field").value = txt;   
}

function changeToHash(txt){
      alert(window.txt);
      var password = "@Utils.Hash(txt)";
      document.getElementById("password_field").value = password;        
}
```

In method @Utils.Hash i need pass one string, and i want put the value of txt.
But i got the error "The name 'txt' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: Probably relevant: [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13840429)

Comment: What does `@Utils` relate to?

Comment: You might want to have another look at how variables work. Also get rid of that legacy `var` and use `let` and `const` instead.

Comment: ``@Utils.Hash(${txt})`` use "`" instead of "

Comment: @jarmod Utils is one static class where i have the method Hash

Comment: Right, but is this some UI framework that allows you to inject function calls into HTML input elements? Which framework? You didn't tag anything but javascript.

Comment: @Ameer Like this? var password = "@Utils.Hash('${txt}')" i got the error "Too many characters in character literal"

Comment: @jarmod ASPNETCORE razor pages C#

Comment: @jarmod yes :) I only pass argument in method

Comment: @Andreas yes, i change to let but i want pass variable txt in var password = "@Utils.Hash('${txt}')""

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass js variable to C# code,you can try to pass `@Utils.GeneratePass()` to `@Utils.Hash()`:

```
var txt;

function change(){
    txt = "@Utils.GeneratePass()";      
    document.getElementById("password_field").value = txt;   
}

function changeToHash(txt){
      alert(window.txt);
      var password = "@Utils.Hash(Utils.GeneratePass())";
      document.getElementById("password_field").value = password;        
}
```